# C - Socket TCP - Infinite loop with read

Tags: c, sockets, loops, tcp

I have a problem when I want to execute two consecutive times the read function Address to retrieve all the data sent by the server.

I read once then read create an infinity loop.

Code :

```
        char   buff[50] = {0};

        nbytes = 1;
        while (nbytes > 0)
        {
            nbytes = read(m_socket, buff, sizeof(buff));
        }
```

---

why read create infinity loop ? is not the "while" the problem.

thank you for your answers.

Comment: What is the type of `nbytes`? Is the socket a normal blocking one?

Comment: Yes I read , you see an error in my code?
m_socket the variable is the correct descriptor initialized with the socket() function

Comment: read must returner 0 but the loop is in the function read . did not while that is infinity

Answer (score -1):

`socket(2)` gives you a *blocking* file descriptor, meaning a system call like `read(2)` blocks until there's <strike>enough</strike> some data available to fulfill your request, or end of stream (for TCP) happens (return value `0`), or some error happens (return value `-1`).

This means you never get out of your `while` loop until you hit an error, or the other side closes the connection.

#### Edit 0:

@EJP is thankfully here to correct me, as usual - `read(2)` blocks until *any* data is available (not the whole thing you requested, as I initially stated above), including an end-of-stream or an error.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer.
Why if I write two consecutive read ( m_socket , buff , sizeof ( buff ) ) ; 2 nd read creates an infinite loop?

Comment: nbytes is never 0 or -1.

Comment: Because for the first read you have 50 bytes available to be read, and for the second you probably don't, so the read **blocks**.

Comment: I tried with 2 buffer , buff and buff2 but it's the same result

Comment: You are not reading (or not understanding) what I am saying. Get a book on sockets programming, or find an online tutorial. You are missing the very basic things. Learn them first.

Comment: I understand what you have written , however the problem arises when the received data is higher than the buffer

Comment: TCP socket is a *stream of bytes*. You will read from it until the remote side of the connection closes its socket.

Comment: so I need is one read to read all the data even if it exceeds the buffer size ?

Comment: You need some higher level logic to know when to stop reading. This is usually called an **application protocol**.

Comment: It doesn't block until all the bytes you have requested are available. It blocks until at least one byte is available, or end of stream, or an error.

Comment: but reading stops when nbytes is 0 right?
with this code : while ((nbytes = read(m_socket, message->mess, sizeof(message->mess))) > 0)
printf("res server : %s \n", buff);

Comment: Return value of `0` from `read` only happens when other side cleanly closes the connection.

Comment: Oh agree it is clearer thank ! how can I know if I have received all the bytes ?

Comment: my goal is to make a small telnet

Comment: Count them - that's what that return value is for. Or, if your application protocol has variable length messages, parse the input and read more until you find the message delimiter.

Comment: how do telnet to know the delimiter used ?

Comment: Read the RFC - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854. There are open source implementations you can look at (OpenBSD/FreeBSD/Linux/etc.).